# suds.client produces 503 error -> how to catch it

Tags: python, soap, suds

Hej,

im writing a script accessing a soap resource (http://chemspell.nlm.nih.gov/axis/SpellAid.jws?wsdl) which is sometimes giving a 503 http status (after several 1000 queries...)

The suds.client module then crashes with a unspecific exception which i am able to catch by a try except statement but i was not able to test this exception for the actual 503 http status.

So the code for catching this problem looks like this right now:

```
for i in range(9):
    try:
        result = client.service.getSugList(query, 'All databases')
        success = True
        break
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        pass
    except Exception, e:
        if e[0] == 503:
            print "e[0] == 503"
        if 503 in e:
            print "503 in e"
        if e is (503, u'Service Temporarily Unavailable'):
            print "e is (503, u'Service Temporarily Unavailable')"                
        if e == (503, u'Service Temporarily Unavailable'):
            print "e == (503, u'Service Temporarily Unavailable')"                                
        raise ChemSpellException, \
              "Uncaught exception raised by suds.client: %s" % e
if success is False:
    raise ChemSpellException, \
          "Got too many timeouts or 503 errors from ChemSpell web service."
```

which results in the following output:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "suds.client"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scripts/chembl_chemspell_synonyms.py", line 49, in <module>
    synonyms_unique = chemspell.get_synonyms_list(value)
  File "/net/netfile2/ag-russell/bq_ppucholt/hd-analytics/PyHDA/sources/chemspell.py", line 82, in get_synonyms_list
    chemspell_syns = get_synonyms(syn)
  File "/net/netfile2/ag-russell/bq_ppucholt/hd-analytics/PyHDA/sources/chemspell.py", line 45, in get_synonyms
    "Uncaught exception raised by suds.client: %s" % e
PyHDA.sources.chemspell.ChemSpellException: Uncaught exception raised by suds.client: (503, u'Service Temporarily Unavailable')
```

So none of my if clauses was able to detect the Exception and i have no idea what to try next to catch it specifically. It is hard to provide a minimal example which fails regularly since it is dependent on the server side and this exception pops up like once a day when the script runs continuesly. Are there any further informations i can provide? Do you have any idea which if clauses to test?

Cheers,
Pascal

Comment: `503 != "503"` in Python

Comment: Have you fixed this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    if e[0] == 503:
```

I just discovered that exceptions where subscriptable, thanks.

```
    if e is (503, u'Service Temporarily Unavailable'):
```

Looks like you're confusing the identity operator ("is") for the equality operator ("==")

```
    if e == (503, u'Service Temporarily Unavailable'):
```

an exception is an exception, not a tuple

```
    raise ChemSpellException, \
          "Uncaught exception raised by suds.client: %s" % e
```

Without this line you'd have a nice error message with the exception type and the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, right now the script is running quite stable though. So im still waiting for the next 503 to happen...

Comment: `if e.args == ((503, u'Service Temporarily Unavailable'), ):` appears to be the proper test. The multiple-ways-boneheaded exception doesn't pass 2 arguments, it passes a tuple in one argument.  See @fledgling answer.

Answer (score 1):

from source code `suds/client.py`

> ```
> def failed(self, binding, error):
>     """
>     Request failed, process reply based on reason
>     @param binding: The binding to be used to process the reply.
>     @type binding: L{suds.bindings.binding.Binding}
>     @param error: The http error message
>     @type error: L{transport.TransportError}
>     """
>     status, reason = (error.httpcode, tostr(error))
>     reply = error.fp.read()
>     log.debug('http failed:\n%s', reply)
>     if status == 500:
>         if len(reply) > 0:
>             r, p = binding.get_fault(reply)
>             self.last_received(r)
>             return (status, p)
>         else:
>             return (status, None)
>     if self.options.faults:
>         raise Exception((status, reason))
>     else:
>         return (status, None)
> ```

They are just raising `Exception` in the following line with parameter tuple (status code and reason),

> raise Exception((status, reason))

You can catch 503 as,

```
try:
    # some code
except Exception as err:
    if (503, u'Service Temporarily Unavailable') in err:
        # here is your 503
```